# get RESTful list with large amount of parameters

Tags: javascript, angularjs, restful-architecture, restful-url

I want to give users of my application to specify search parameters with query builder.
Something like this
http://dncrews.com/angular-elastic-builder/examples/
Or this
http://mfauveau.github.io/angular-query-builder/

Front-end which is written in AngularJS comunicates over HTTP with back-end.
On back-end i want to implement RESTful API. 
And i cannot find any recomendations how to get list (which usually retrived throug HTTP GET request) with large amount of search parameters in RESTful way. 
In my case user can build query that will exhaust URL length limit. Because of that i cannot use GET request type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A common approach is to use `POST` to create a `/search-criteria` resource which contains all your parameters. Then do the `GET` with a query parameter `?searchCriteria={id}`.

Comment: I like this approach, but it requires 2 requests to server. Maybe create resource /search, which will return results after receiving query through POST ?

Comment: You can do that if you choose. Strictly speaking, it is RPC and not RESTful, but it's not an uncommon approach. For very complex search criteria, you might want to allow users to remember their choices so they don't have to re-enter them. Also, I very much doubt the two requests will be noticeable to end users, but that's what testing is for.

Comment: I worry more about additional requests for server to handle.
I have desided to implement saved search query as separate resource. So users can store templates and reuse them or modify query and request different search configurations without storing them.

Answer (score 1):

Simple, use POST. It doesn't have any limitations on amount of data.